# AngularJs 'TabsCtrl' is not a function, got undefined .Net

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5

Me encontraba tomando un ejemplo de internet de cómo crear SPA, pero estoy atorado, la cuestión es que utiliza algunos *modules*, que se anidan y crean controles con dependencia hacia los *modules*, el problema es que no puedo utilizar las dependencias de `ui.bootstrap`, o algo no estoy entendiendo bien, traté de abstraer los códigos que me dan error, pero no logro resolverlo.

Codigo :

```js
var commonModule = angular.module('common',['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);    

var mainModule = angular.module('main', ['common']);

var customerModule = angular.module('customer', ['common']);

customerModule.controller('TabsCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {
  $scope.tabs = [
    { title:'Dynamic Title 1', content:'Dynamic content 1' },
    { title:'Dynamic Title 2', content:'Dynamic content 2', disabled: true }
  ];

  $scope.alertMe = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $window.alert('You\'ve selected the alert tab!');
    });
  };

  $scope.model = {
    name: 'Tabs'
  };
});
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
  form.tab-form-demo .tab-pane {
    margin: 20px 20px;
  }
</style>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html data-ng-app="main" lang="en ng-app"> 
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div data-ng-controller="TabsCtrl">
  <p>Select a tab by setting active binding to true:</p>
 

  <uib-tabset active="active">
    <uib-tab index="0" heading="Static title">Static content</uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="$index + 1" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" disable="tab.disabled">
      {{tab.content}}
    </uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="3" select="alertMe()">
      <uib-tab-heading>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i> Alert!
      </uib-tab-heading>
      I've got an HTML heading, and a select callback. Pretty cool!
    </uib-tab>
  </uib-tabset>

  <hr />

 

  <uib-tabset active="activeJustified" justified="true">
    <uib-tab index="0" heading="Justified">Justified content</uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="1" heading="SJ">Short Labeled Justified content</uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="2" heading="Long Justified">Long Labeled Justified content</uib-tab>
  </uib-tabset>

  <hr />


  <hr />

</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es un diagrama de tus módulos, quizas te de mejor idea de lo que está pasando. Las flechas indican quien depende de quien.

[image: modulos]

El módulo marcado en azul `main` es el que estas usando para hacerle *bootstrap* a la aplicación con `ng-app` y este solo depende del módulo `common` en azul claro.

Tu controller `TabsCtrl` se encuentra declarado en el módulo `customer` y este por supuesto nunca se carga ya que de acuerdo a tus dependencias solo `main` y `common` son usados por la aplicación; `customer` es **declarado** pero nunca **mergeado** con nadie.

Cuando declaras que un módulo depende de otro lo que estas haciendo es que todos los controllers, directivas y demás estructuras que pertenezcan a ese módulo estén también disponibles en el módulo que le está haciendo referencia.

La solución es sencilla, declara `customer` como una dependencia de `main`

```
var mainModule = angular.module('main', ['common', 'customer']);
```

Este es el resultado

[image: resultado deseado]

Ahora `main` tiene acceso a `TabsCtrl`.

Revisa el snippet.

```js
var commonModule = angular.module('common', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);

var mainModule = angular.module('main', ['common', 'customer']);

var customerModule = angular.module('customer', ['common']);

customerModule.controller('TabsCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.tabs = [{
    title: 'Dynamic Title 1',
    content: 'Dynamic content 1'
  }, {
    title: 'Dynamic Title 2',
    content: 'Dynamic content 2',
    disabled: true
  }];

  $scope.alertMe = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $window.alert('You\'ve selected the alert tab!');
    });
  };

  $scope.model = {
    name: 'Tabs'
  };
});
```

```css
form.tab-form-demo .tab-pane {
  margin: 20px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.2.0.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div data-ng-app="main">
  <div data-ng-controller="TabsCtrl">
    <p>Select a tab by setting active binding to true:</p>
    <uib-tabset active="active">
      <uib-tab index="0" heading="Static title">Static content</uib-tab>
      <uib-tab index="$index + 1" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" disable="tab.disabled">
        {{tab.content}}
      </uib-tab>
      <uib-tab index="3" select="alertMe()">
        <uib-tab-heading>
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i> Alert!
        </uib-tab-heading>
        I've got an HTML heading, and a select callback. Pretty cool!
      </uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>
    <hr />
    <uib-tabset active="activeJustified" justified="true">
      <uib-tab index="0" heading="Justified">Justified content</uib-tab>
      <uib-tab index="1" heading="SJ">Short Labeled Justified content</uib-tab>
      <uib-tab index="2" heading="Long Justified">Long Labeled Justified content</uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>
    <hr />
    <hr />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Impresionante , gracias por tomarte el tiempo para responder de esa manera.

Comment: @CesarPerezRamirez Gracias. Bienvenido a SOes

Comment: trate de abstraer de una manera simple la problematica de tal manera que fuera mas simple de leerse por la persona que lo iba a responder y tambien para mi , pero la problematica es un poco mas compleja , La actividad que estoy realizando maneja un doble routing uno sobre MVC de .Net y otro de angular, el problema es que no carga el ui.bootstrap no se por que , el ejemplo completo esta en esta pagina http://www.codemag.com/article/1605081 , deberia de abrir un nuevo post con todo el codigo ?

Comment: Creo que deberías pero antes revisa que en tu ejemplo tienes `<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/....` cuando debería ser `<script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/...`; le falta `https:`, las urls de todos los scripts están mal escritas, quizás sea la causa. Aparte de eso no debería causarte problemas ya que como ves en el snippet que te puse en la respuesta todas están funcionando correctamente.

Comment: En mi projecto tengo las librerias localmente, y si el ejemplo que me mandaste funciona de lujo , uno de los problemas esque commonModule sirve como padre para otros  Modules , y cuando se hace el routing reemplaza dinamicamente los controllers y por alguna razon deja de tener acceso a las dependencias , probare reformulando la pregunta con el scenario complejo , te agradezco mucho la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Por una lado estas agregando el controlador `TabsCtrl` al modulo `customer`.

Pero estas instanciando la ng-app `main`.

Remplaza el nombre de la app en el tag `<html>`.

```
<html data-ng-app="customer" lang="en ng-app">
```